# how can I solve perhaps the designated entry point is not set error?

Tags: swift, flutter, dart

I tried to run my flutter app in xcode.It gives me such an error :"Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?" How can I solve this error? [image: for better understanding you can have a look to this image]
I assume  this problem is related to swift language.
[image: maybe the problem is smt related to configuration]

[image: main file]

I tried to delete launch screen and main storyboard files,then generate new ones.However it did not help me.Maybe I missed some steps.

Answer (score 1):

As the error said, you are missing entry point for Main storyboard. Open `Main` file, then tick on `Is Initial View Controller`. You also need to change `Launch Screen File` to correct `LaunchScreen.storyboard` instead of `Main.storyboard`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you I did what you said.However now I get an error like that : Command CreateUniversalBinary failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: So weird, can you show the Main storyboard? @FaridAhmadov

Comment: yes sure thanks for helping me

Comment: I attached image

Comment: I've researched this, but unfortunately, no luck. Sorry, I can't help you fix this issue. However, if I were in your shoes, I would try to clean and build the project again by deleting `DerivedData` folder. @FaridAhmadov